# unfolding a file on linux

Tags: linux, file, folding

I have a huge textfile, approx 400.000 lines 80 charachters wide on liux.

Need to "unfold" the file, merging four lines into one
ending up having 1/4 of the lines, each line 80*4 charachters long.

any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easier way to do it with awk would be:

```
awk '{ printf $0 } (NR % 4 == 0) { print }' filename
```

Although if you wanted to protect against ending up without a trailing newline it gets a little more complicated:

```
awk '{ printf $0 } (NR % 4 == 0) { print } END { if (NR % 4 != 0) print }' filename
```

Comment: Cute, though I suspect shares the "sometime lacks a trailing newline" problem with the perl solution suggested by kmkaplan. None-the-less, props for clarity and terseness.

Comment: I've added a more complicated example that fixes that problem. Still relatively simple.

Answer (score 10):

```
perl -pe 'chomp if (++$i % 4);'
```

Comment: This is beautifully short. It seems to lack the final newline in the output, though.

Comment: That must be because the number of lines in your file is not a multiple of four.

Answer (score 2):

I hope I understood your question correctly. You have an input line like this (except your lines are longer):

```
abcdef
ghijkl
mnopqr
stuvwx
yz0123
456789
ABCDEF
```

You want output like this:

```
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx
yz0123456789ABCDEF
```

The following awk program should do it:

```
{ line = line $0 }
(NR % 4) == 0 { print line; line = "" }
END { if (line != "") print line }
```

Run it like this:

```
awk -f merge.awk data.txt
```